# IndexError on list.pop() in list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

To learn python I am implementing [Bulls and Cows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulls_and_cows). So I need to generate a 'random' number. I tried this:

```
possibilities = range(10)
number = "".join([str(possibilities.pop(random.choice(possibilities))) for i in range(4)])
```

Which I thought was a nice solution to the problem, but once in every couple of runs I get an IndexError on that line: `IndexError: pop index out of range`

So it looks like random.choice() gives me a non existent index. How come?
Or am I making a wrong assumption and is the problem something else entirely?
Come to think of it, I haven't got a clue how to debug a statement like this, any pointers on that?

**Edit**
My first solution was of the procedural kind:

```
for i in range(4):
    idx = random.choice(possibilities)
    number = number + str(possibilities[idx])
    del possibilities[idx]
```

This code seems to do the exact same thing as the one-liner above, but has no problems whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't randomly choosing *indices*, you're choosing *values* from the list. What if you pick 9 after a lower number or two has been `pop`ped from the list?

Instead, use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
number = "".join(map(str, random.sample(range(10), 4)))
```

Comment: You are right, how could I have missed that.. Thanks for this great solution!